# Prevent app from being launched at boot if manually launched by user

Tags: android, startup, android-broadcastreceiver

I've set my application to be launched at system startup and it does so. The problem is that it takes about **~30 seconds** between the homescreen showing up and my app to be launched. This may be a problem if the user doesn't wait.

My idea is to prevent the app from being re-launched when the system broadcasts the message IF it is already running.

**So, basically, I'm looking for either solution:**

- Decrease wait time between system start and app start **AND / OR**;
- Prevent app from being launched when the message is received if it is already running.

*The first topic is something I want to achieve regardless, but I don't control when android will fire the message. If I could achieve both, it would be great, but I'd settle for the second option.*

---

I don't think it's necessary to show this, but I've set everything in the Manifest (i.e `BOOT_COMPLETED`) and this is my code, where `MyNamedActivity` is my main activity (**working code**):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) && AppController.getUsuarioLogado() == null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyNamedActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

*Note: Removing `addFlags` line causes the app to cash.*

Comment: you cannot detect if the app is running or if the message as arrived yet?

Comment: You mean check if the app is running when the message arrives? I didn't know it was possible. I could try that. It will depend on what the code will consider as 'app running' since I want to prevent it even if the user opens the app and leaves all before the message. I'll look it up @TomásRodrigues

Comment: Also, consider on make a fancy animated launchscreen, to don't lose the user interest

Comment: That's not an option. The spashscreen will take 30 seconds to be called and x seconds more for it to finish it's animation. @TomásRodrigues

Comment: have you tried making the activity `singleInstance`? That way it doesn't try to relaunch an already existing `MyNamedActivity` after boot. Otherwise, save the message state somewhere and exit the boot-launch early if you can read the message state in `onReceive`.